# кастомные поля в Django

Tags: django, postgresql

В модели определено такое поле:

```
priority = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

Затем в таблице базы данных PostgreSQL это поле определено так:

```
priority integer NOT NULL DEFAULT currval('table_id_seq'::regclass)
```

При создании новой строки по умолчанию это поле принимает значение равное текущему ID,  что мне и нужно, но джанго затирает значение единицей.

Каким образом можно объявить это поле типом Integer в контексте DjangoORM, но ответственность по установке дефолтового значения возложить на бэкенд постгреса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открыл для себя триггеры. Как раз под мою проблему подходит:

```
CREATE FUNCTION mod_testos() RETURNS trigger AS $mod_testos$
BEGIN
    NEW.dup_id = currval((TG_RELNAME || '_id_seq')::regclass);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$mod_testos$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_mod_testos BEFORE INSERT ON table_testos
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE mod_testos();
```